# Argue for whether or not the Fourier series for f $x \cos(x)$ converges uniformly or in $L^2$.

Tags: convergence-divergence, fourier-series

Consider the function $f \in C_{st}$ which on the interval $]-\pi,\pi[$ is equal to the function $x \cos(x)$. Then I have to argue whether or not the Fourier series for $f$ converges uniformly or in $L^2$.

I have said that as $x \cos(x)$ is a well known continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ and that the limits $\lim_{x \rightarrow \pi^-} x \cos(x)$ and $ \lim_{x \rightarrow -\pi^+} x \cos(x)$ exists $f$ is especially continous. Futhermore that $f \in C^1_{st}$ as $x \cos(x)$ is $C^1$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and the derivative of f $ \cos(x) - x\sin(x)$is a well known continous function and $C^1$ in the inverval $]-\pi,\pi[$. Thus the Fourier series for $f$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$ towards $f$.

However I am not sure about the converges in $L^2$. From a definition in my book a sequence $\{f_n\} \in C_{st}$ is said to converge towards $f in C_{st}$ in $L_2$ if $||f-f_n|| \rightarrow 0$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$. But I am not sure how to prove or disprove that? Can you help me?

Comment: The Fourier series cannot converge uniformly because the limits at $\pm \pi$ are not the same. The sum of  a convergent FS is always periodic. The FS of any $L^{2}$ function converges in $L^{2}$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I did not know that.

Comment: But if the limits were the same, the FS would converge in this instance?

Comment: If you have a continuously differentiable periodic function then the FS does converge uniformly

Comment: Just to be sure: in my case $f$ is not continuous at $\pm \pi$ as the limit is not the same?

Comment: Continuity is not the problem. You can extend $f$ to a  continuous function on the closed interval $[-\pi,\pi]$.  The problem is $f(\pi)\neq f(-\pi)$ so $f$ is not periodic with period $2\pi$.

Comment: Thank you Kavi for the explanation. That is noted for my exam! But I still don't understand the convergence in $L^2$. Do I have to prove that $x \cos(x)$ is a function in $L^2$. Thus as you have stated it converges in $L^2$?

Comment: The function is bouded and continuous on the interval. This implies that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |x \cos x)|^{2} dx <\infty$, so the function does belong to $L^{2}$.

Comment: Thanks but the only problem is that I do not have a sentence in my book about Fourier series saying that the FS of any $L^2$ function converges in $L^2$ only that a sequence $\{f_n\}$ from $C_{st}$ is said to converge towards $f \in C_{st}$ in $L^2$ if $||f-f_n|| \rightarrow 0 $ for $n \rightarrow \infty$

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_n$ be the fourier series of $f$. You said that $(S_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$, that is :
\begin{align}
\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists N >0, \forall n > N, \| f-S_n\|_{\infty} < \varepsilon
\end{align}

Now, look at $|f(t)-S_n(t)|^2$ : if n > N, then it is always less than $\varepsilon^2$. So
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} |f-S_n|^2 < 2\pi \varepsilon^2
\end{align}

and now you can conclude

Comment: Is there any particular reason we look at $|f(t)-S_n(t)|^2 < \epsilon^2$ and not just $|f(t)-S_n(t)| < \epsilon$? And what do we need the integral for? I am not so familiar yet with  Fourier series so I hope you can elaborate a little. Thanks for helping though :)

Comment: It's because it's the $L^2$ norm. In fact, it comes from an inner product, and you can do nice geometry with it.

Comment: Ok thanks makes sense. And the integral is always less than $2\pi \epsilon^2$ as $|f(t) - S_n(t)|^2 < \epsilon^2$ and as the integral is from $[0,2\pi]$ but how do I now conclude? I am not really sure. This is an earlier exam question in Analysis which I am studying for so it would be nice to know. Thanks man :)

Comment: I just found a sentence in my book I think I can use. Do you mind verifying? "Let $f \in C_{st}$ Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and assume that $f$ is identical $0$ (not sut what this means) on an open set which contains $K$. Then the Fourier series for $f$ converges uniformly towards $0$ on $K$. Doesn't this satisfy $$|f-f_n|| \rightarrow 0 $$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: The Fourier series of $f$ is a sequence of functions $(S_n)$. You can ask if this sequence converges. But convergence is a metric thing : if $d$ is a distance, the sequence $(S_n)$ converges to $f$ if
\begin{align}
\forall \varepsilon >0, ~\exists N, \forall n > N, d(S_n,f) < \varepsilon
\end{align}

On the space of functions, there are many distance that arose from norms : $L^2$ distance and $||.||_{\infty}$ distance here.

Provided $f$ is $C^1_{st}$, $(S_n)$ converges in $||.||_{\infty}$ distance to $f$. And you can controll the $L^2$ distance with $||.||_{\infty}$ by its definition.